Solutions for $x=tx'+2\sqrt{-x'}$ differential equation
I was trying to solve this equation:
$$ x=tx'+2\sqrt{-x'} $$
It is Clairaut's equation, so I put $x'=p$. Then:
$$ x=tp+2\sqrt{-p} \ |'$$
$$ x'=p+tp' + 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt{-p}}\cdot \left( -p' \right) $$
$$ p=p+tp' - \frac{p'}{\sqrt{-p}} $$
$$ 0=tp' - \frac{p'}{\sqrt{-p}} = p' \left( t-\frac{1}{\sqrt{-p}} \right) $$
$$ p' = 0 \vee t=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-p}}$$
$$ p = C \vee t^2 = -\frac{1}{p} $$
$$ x' = C \vee x' = \frac{-1}{t^2} $$
$$ x = C_1t + C_2 \vee x = \frac{1}{t} + C_3$$
Putting it back to equation I'm getting $ C_1=-\frac{1}{4} C_2^2, C_3 = 0 $
So solutions are:
$$ x = -\frac{1}{4}C_2^2 t+C_2 \vee x=\frac{1}{t}$$
and both works. However Wolfram says that there are two solutions:
$$ x \left(t\right) = \frac{4\left( C_1-t \right)}{C_1^2} \vee x \left(t\right) = - \frac{4\left( C_1+t \right)}{C_1^2}$$
I think both of them are some kind the same (decreasing linear) like my first solution and there is no hyperbolic solution. Is wolfram wrong or I am?

You are correct for $x=1/t$. I deleted my bad answer.
